# Search sheet and copy cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet called Names which has information on multiple individuals. I want to go through an entire column searching for the name of a person, the name of the person is the value that is input into `textBox1`. Once the name is found it will go over two columns where there address is stored and put that value into a variable. Once that is done I want to then go to another sheet called Summary and paste that value into cell `L2`. I know how to loop through the values but I am getting stuck with the rest. Below shows what I have so far:

```
Set rng = Range("C1:C1000")

For Each cell In rng
   If cell.Value <> textBox1.value Then
End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
If cell.Value = textBox1.value Then
    var = cell.offset(0,2)
    sheets("Summary").range("L2") = var
End If
```

Comment: I was trying to do that and it wouldn't same to work but it seems to be working now for some weird reason but thanks because that worked perfectly